# Docker: bind `/uploads` directory to Amazon S3 Storage

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to migrate my php site from a virtual machine to a docker container. My site persists all uploaded files to the `uploads` directory. Now I would like to transfer all the files to S3 Storage and save further uploads also to Amazon S3. But I don't want to rewrite the php file uploader class. Is it possible to create in Docker the symlink folder, or virtual folder, so that all writes and reads on `uploads/**` path are 'redirected' to S3 Storage.

Docker supports [S3 Storage Driver](https://docs.docker.com/registry/storage-drivers/s3/) but I am new to docker, and don't know how the folder should be mapped to the s3 storage in dockerfile. No other examples I have found.

Thank you for your help.

**Update:** Please see the Taruns [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565323/2436109). If you also know, that AWS Storage Gateway on hosting environment, is the only one good solution, please upvote or share your thoughts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The S3 storage link that your posted is for Docker Registry setup and not for Docker volumes. What you need is to map a folder on your hard drive to the container. So let's assume you map `/var/www/uploads` on host to your `uploads` inside the container.

Now what you want is `/var/www/uploads` to be actually mounted as an S3 backed folder. For this Amazon had launched an AWS Storage Gateway. You can use that to create a S3 backed folder on your system. Below is an article from Amazon that details how to configure the same

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/ManagingLocalStorage-common.html

Comment: Oh, thank you for the clarification. Does it mean it can't be solved on docker level. We have to configurate the hosting environment for this? But if I don't have access to the hosting environment, I would like to prepair the docker image only, so that it can be run anywhere.

Comment: Well I doubt for 2 reasons. If you look at their setup it says `Choose an Instance Type we recommend m4.xlarge instance type` so running it inside a container makes no sense. Next they provide pre-installed setups, so you can do it just everywhere/anywhere

Comment: Thank you for your time, Tarun. Last thing I would like to ask to get the clear  picture: When a browser requests some uploaded image, the request goes inside our container to the `upload` folder,  it then goes to the backed folder in our system `/var/wwww/uploads`, and from there 
 the AWS Storage Gateway handles the `read`. When the file doesn't exists it goes to the cloud, downloads the file, and gives it the way back to the user.  Is the pipeline, I understand, correct? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, see this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/WhatIsStorageGateway.html

Comment: Thanks again! I'll start also the bounty, perhaps there is some solution within docker, so that the hosting environment stays intact. But after all researches I also doubt, so this should be the best answer, later I'll accept it as an answer. Thanks you.

Comment: Sure, no worries